# Xcode - Customize "About This App"

Tags: xcode, about-box

How do I change the "About this app" window of an app in Xcode? I've made a little app, but I don't know how to change this little thing. Thank you for your help :D

Answer (score 1):

In your MainMenu.xib, change to the target-action of the menu item "About myApp" to your custom action.

Then in your action, you can do whatever you want. For example, you can display a window that you've either designed in a nib file or created programmatically.

Comment: Can you explain in more detail? I've just started programming in Cocoa... Where can I changer te target-action? Thank you very much for helping me!

Comment: In your MainMenu.xib. Click on your "myApp" menu (The first one on left). Then click on "About myApp" menu item and drag your mouse to your controller that has the action and choose this action.

Comment: Check the documentation below :
http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/LoadingResources/CocoaNibs/CocoaNibs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000051i-CH4-SW32